# How to avoid the warning screen of SSL error

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have installed `SSL` on my server. But when I go to the page of my website that is on `SSL` it shows me the warning page first. I have to install the `SSL` certificate. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: no. either you install the cert so your browser accepts it, or you keep getting the error. or, you get a valid cert issued by a certificate authority that your browser recognizes.

Comment: but what about facebook and google run on https but my browser never asks for installing the certificate

Comment: You can get a free Class 1 certificate from [Startcom](https://cert.startcom.org/). Its trusted by most desktop and mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Get the certificate signed by a CA.

That's what Facebook and Google did.